# Moving require config to external file

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Right now in my header I've got this code:

```
<script src="/js/libs/requirejs/requirejs.min.js"></script>
<script>
    require.config({
        baseUrl: "/js/libs",
        paths: {
            jquery: "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min",
            jqueryUi: "jquery-ui/mapa/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min",
            portal: "../dev/portal"
        },
        shim: {
            "jqueryUi": {
                export:"ui" ,
                deps: ['jquery']
            }
        }
    });
    require( ["portal"], function(portal) {
            portal.config={'var': 'value'};
            portal.init();
        }
    );
</script>
```

I want to do it the right way using data-main attr:

```
<script data-main="/js/build/req-init" src="/js/libs/requirejs/requirejs.min.js"></script>
<script>
    require( ["portal"], function(portal) {
            portal.config={'var': 'value'};
            portal.init();
        }
    );
</script>
```

and move all `require.config` to that file (/js/build/req-init.js).

Problem is that it searches `potral.js` file in root directory because data-main file isn't loaded yet and it doesn't know paths. How to delay execution of `require(["portal"])` ?
I need to have `portal.init()` in HTML because of `portal.config` - variables will be defined with php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have apply a different pattern in our html5 application to move requireJS config to an external file.

**directory structure**

```
{webroot}/
   html/
   js/
      apps/
          conf.js
          main.js
      libs/
          jquery-1.11.1.min.js
          ...
```

**../js/app/conf.js**

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: "../js",
    paths: {
        app:      "../js/app",
        libs:     "../js/libs",
        jquery:   "libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min",
        jqueryUi: "libs/jquery-ui/mapa/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min",
        portal:   "../dev/portal"
    },
    shim: {
        "jqueryUi": {
            export:"ui" ,
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});
```

**../js/app/main.js**

```
require( ["portal"], function(portal) {
        portal.config={'var': 'value'};
        portal.init();
    }
);
```

**inside html**

```
<scrip src="/js/app/conf.js"></script>
<script data-main="app/main" src="/js/libs/requirejs/requirejs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how is this able to work if require is already used in conf.js and then requirejs.min.js is loaded?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake calling require(conf) inside conf.js. I have fixed it. According to document (Configuration Options: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config), you can define the config object as the global variable require before require.js is loaded.

Comment: oh, well, than we agree on this :)

Answer (score 2):

the trick is to use your config in a little different format and load it before your main script. This is the only way which is really reliable to load an "external" config in all cases:

config.js:

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: "/js/libs",
    paths: {
        jquery: "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min",
        jqueryUi: "jquery-ui/mapa/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min",
        portal: "../dev/portal"
    },
    shim: {
        "jqueryUi": {
            export:"ui" ,
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

req-init.js

```
require( ["portal"], function(portal) {
  portal.config={'var': 'value'};
  portal.init();
});
```

html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
<script data-main="/js/build/req-init" src="/js/libs/requirejs/requirejs.min.js"></script>
```

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config

for further optimizations (because I see you have a build folder) I would concatenate the config.js with the requirejs.min.js (config before require) to lose a request